# How to add nested form in rails 7

Tags: nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I create application for making routes with rails 7 stimulus.
First question: How to use in form only available location? Idk and i think using wrong methods like("#{Location.first.title}") in form.select. How to get available locations by another way?
Second: My form create a new location but i don't want it. All location must be created separate. From another form. I think something redundant.
May be a add redundant references.

```
locations_controller.rb

...
def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:user_id, :title, :comment, :description, :address, :country, :city, :state, :image, :short_discription, :latitude, :longitude)
    end

tours_controller.rb
...
def tour_params
      params.require(:tour).permit(:name, :comment, :description, :user_id, :location, locations_attributes: %i[user_id title address _destroy comment])
    end

models/location.rb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tour

model/tour.rb
 has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :tour
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

tours/_form.html.haml

= form_for @tour, data: {controller: "nested-form", nested_form_wrapper_selector_value: '.nested-form-wrapper'} do |f|
  - if @tour.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@tour.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this tour from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @tour.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: "#{current_user.id}"
  .field
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description
  %template(data-nested-form-target="template")
    = f.fields_for :locations, Location.new, child_index: "NEW_RECORD" do |location_fields|
      = render "tours/tour_location_form", f: location_fields
    = f.fields_for :locations do |location_fields|
      = render "tours/tour_location_form", f: location_fields
  / Inserted elements will be injected before that target.
  %div(data-nested-form-target="target")
  %button(data-action="nested-form#add" type="button") Add location
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'

tours/tour_location_form.html.haml
.nested-form-wrapper(data-new-record="#{f.object.new_record?}")
  = f.label :title
  = f.select :title, ["#{Location.first.title}", "#{Location.second.title}", "#{Location.find(6).title}"]
  = f.label :comment
  = f.text_field :comment
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  %button(data-action="nested-form#remove" type="button") Remove location
  = f.hidden_field :_destroy



routes.rb
...
resources :locations
resources :tours

schema.rb
create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "image"
    t.text "short_discription"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "tour_id"
    t.string "comment"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["tour_id"], name: "index_locations_on_tour_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_locations_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tours", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "location"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "comment"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tours_on_user_id"
  end
```